# PHP - Save data $_POST array into database mysql

Tags: php

I am trying to send data from multiple Radio Button with 
`name="answer<?php echo$data[id]?>"`.
with this `$_POST[answer[]]`how I can save data ?

here is the code.
thanks.

```
`<form method="post" action="proses.php">`<tbody>
<?php
$no=1;
$getdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pertanyaan where kategori='pekerjaan' order by kategori desc");
        while($data=mysql_fetch_array($getdata)){
        ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $no ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data[pertanyaan]?></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="answer<?php echo $data[id] ?>" value="ss"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="answer<?php echo $data[id] ?>" value="s"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="answer<?php echo $data[id] ?>" value="b"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="answer<?php echo $data[id] ?>" value="ts"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="answer<?php echo $data[id] ?>" value="sts"></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please show output of `var_dump($data)` placed in the loop?

Comment: How do you submit the value .. i don't see the code,,,

Answer (score 1):

You need to put square [] brackets in the name of radio battons.

```
<form method="post" action="proses.php">`<tbody>
<?php
$no=1;
$getdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pertanyaan where kategori='pekerjaan' order by kategori desc");
    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($getdata)){
    ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $no ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data[pertanyaan]?></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $data[id] ?>]" value="ss"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $data[id] ?>]" value="s"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $data[id] ?>]" value="b"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $data[id] ?>]" value="ts"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $data[id] ?>]" value="sts"></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <form method="post" action="proses.php">`<tbody>
    <?php
      $no=1;
      $getdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pertanyaan where kategori='pekerjaan' order by kategori desc");
    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($getdata)){
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $no ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data[pertanyaan]?></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $data[id] ?>]" value="ss"></td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $data[id] ?>]" value="s"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $data[id] ?>]" value="b"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $data[id] ?>]" value="ts"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $data[id] ?>]" value="sts"></td>
    </tr>
  </form>
   //process.php

    <?php 
     if(isset($_POST)) {

         $getRadio = $_POST['answer'];
            if(count($getRadio) > 0) {

             // While updating data

              foreach($getRadio as $key => $val) {

               $query = "Update  pertanyaan set kategori = $val  WHERE id = $key";
               mysql_query($query);
        }
       //Insert Data

       foreach($getRadio as $key => $val) {

         //$key Reference Id of Table
         // val get checked radio button value
         $query  = "insert into  TABLENAME values('NULL','$val','$key')"; 
         mysql_query($query);
      }
   }

 }?>
```